# error in adding class to a pargraph element which is defined inside document.write() of javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

this is my js code-

```
var str1 = "Wardrobe Makeover";
var str2 = "Female Fashion Makeover";
var str3 = "Male Fashion Makeover";
var menu1=new Array()
menu1[0]= document.write("<p>" + str2.link("http://abc.com/mystylemuse/wardrobe_makeover") + "</p>");
menu1[1]= document.write("<p>" + str2.link("http://abc.com/mystylemuse/female") + "</p>");
menu1[2]= document.write("<p>" + str3.link("http://abc.com/mystylemuse/male") + "</p>");
```

whenever i add a css class name inside `<p>`, like- `document.write("<p class="abc">" + str2.link("http://abc.com/mystylemuse/wardrobe_makeover") + "</p>");` it shows error. please tell me how can i add a class inside `<p>` element.

Comment: This is some really f%$§ed up code :(
document.write returns nothing and should not be used anyway except to scare children. As for your error, you DO notice that you have multiple """??? You need to escape the inner ones: \"

Answer (score 1):

It should be:

`document.write("<p class=\"abc\">" + str2.link("http://abc.com/mystylemuse/wardrobe_makeover") + "</p>");`

Answer (score 0):

If your string includes double quotes, then you can use single quotes as string delimiters, and vice versa.

```
'<p class="abc">'
```

or

```
"<p class='abc'>"
```